# facebook JavaScript SDK - what is the 'your app id' when you just want to use the SDK for the facebook 'Like' button?

Tags: javascript, api, facebook, xfbml

I want to add the facebook 'Like' button to my website, but the JavaScript API is asking for **'your app id'**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

What should I put there?

I could use the iframe code they give, but would prefer to use the XFBML as it will allow me to add more features in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your app in the **[facebook developer section](http://www.facebook.com/developers)** and there you will be assigned app id (application id), that is what you should put in there.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are saying that you should use the "Application ID", which is a long integer, and not the "API Key" or the "Application Secret", both of which are hex strings. Is that correct?

Comment: according to this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/ it's an optional parameter. please try without appid as well, it works for me.